# Why is process.env.PORT ⎮⎮ 8001 not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, backend

I am coding the backend of a website with **MERN**.

This is my code in `server.js`:

```js
import express from "express"
import mongoose from "mongoose"

//App config
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT ⎮⎮ 8001
```

I get a big fat **Error** after typing `npm start`:

```js
file:///Users/.../.../.../.../server.js:6
const port = process.env.PORT ⎮⎮ 8001               

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

If anyone knows how to solve this problem, thank you soooo much.

Thanks in advance,

Emiel

Comment: Because you have some form of big fat pipes instead of the normal `|`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like a copy-paste error.
What you have is [“⎮” U+23AE Integral Extension Unicode Character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+23AE):

```
⎮
```

What is needed is this:

```
|
```

Here's the URL Encoded form:

[image: encodeURI]

```
encodeURI("⎮")
"%E2%8E%AE"
encodeURI("|")
"%7C"
```

Try replacing it with the following:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8001
```